# Jasmin throwing an error for incorrect agruments for iastore

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, jasmin

I am currently writing a compiler for a given language that should compile to the java virtual machine.

I am currently getting arrays to work and I have come to the following problem for the following code in my language

```
package foo
func main() {
    var i int[2];
    i[0] = 5;
}
```

And currently it is compiling to

```
.class  public  test
.super  java/lang/Object
.method  public static  main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
ldc 2
newarray    int
astore  0
aload   0
ldc 0
ldc 5
iastore 0
return
.limit  locals  2    ;over estimate
.limit  stack  20    ;over estimate
.end    method
```

And the following error is being thrown

```
test.j:11: JAS Error Bad arguments for instruction iastore.
    r
     ^
```

Now accurding to https://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--20.html the stack should look like

```
|  value  |
|  index  | 
|array ref|
 _________
```

Which is what I have done so my question is what does this error referring to?

Comment: Possible it refers to the `0` after `iastore`: you write `iastore 0`, but according to the linked documentation all arguments are passed on the stack

Comment: I actually decompiled a java program to check this actually and they indeed do        `12: aload_1
      13: iconst_0
      14: bipush        10
      16: iastore` type things it looks like @ThomasKläger